# why can enum class values of type int not be used as int

Tags: c++, enum-class

I wanted to change an old-style `enum` to `enum class : int`  because of its own scope.

But the compiler complains about using the values in integer arithmetics.
But why - since the enum is explicitly typed as int?

example:

```
  enum class MsgType : int {
    Output = 1,
    Input  = 2,
    Debug  = 3
  };
  enum class MsgSender : int {
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 3
  };


  // later in code
  int id = (MsgType::Input << 16) + (MsgSender::A);
```

produces

> error C2678: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'MyClass::MsgType' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

This seems to be somewhat illogical to me.

Edit:
I am totally aware of the possillity to cast them. But if I would not want them to be convertible, why would i specify the type to be `int`. Especially if the syntax suggest some kind of "inherited from `int`"

Comment: Have you tried casting before shifting? There's likely no shift operator on an enum.

Comment: Because it is still a `class`, not an `int`. That's the point of `enum class`, it's a dedicated type and not just an alias for an integer

Comment: sorry, but its seems illocigal that you switch to a typesafe enum and expect it to be not typesafe. Thats the main difference between new and old enums

Comment: @UnholySheep I would like to compare an enum value more to an object since it is used like one.  and in this case an object of a class that is derived from `int`

Comment: Yes, the syntax is similar. But no it doesn't mean the same. Unfortunate, but nothing really noverl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the feature. Scoped enumerations are not implicitly convertible to integers, so you can't use them in lieu of integers. They are strongly typed by design. If you *want* the implicit conversion, use unscoped enumerations.

```
enum MsgType : int {
  Output = 1,
  Input  = 2,
  Debug  = 3
};
enum MsgSender : int {
  A = 1,
  B = 2,
  C = 3
};
```

Scoping and the specification of an underlying type are orthogonal.

Alternatively, if you only want some operations to be defined, while the enumerations remain strongly typed in general, you can  overload the appropriate operators to accomplish that

```
int operator<<(MsgType, int); // etc
```

> But if I would not want them to be convertible, why would i specify the type to be int

To ensure a certain layout. To follow a specific ABI. To allow forward declaring the type.

Answer (score 3):

Type safety is the main reason to use the new scoped enums (perhaps the name is a bit misleading). If you merely want an enum that is scoped and can implicitly convert to integers you can wrap it in a struct or namespace:

```
struct MsgSender {
   enum Values {
      A = 1,
      B = 2,
      C = 3
   };
};
```

Downside is that the type is now `MsgSender::Values`, but the values are `MsgSender::A` etc.

For a scoped enum you have to `static_cast` to the [`std::underlying_type<MsgSener>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type) to get the integer.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert them explicitly via a static_cast.

```
  int id = (static_cast<uint32_t>(MsgType::Input) << 16) + (static_cast<uint32_t>(MsgSender::A)) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use c++11 scoped enums directly as int, but can cast it into `int`.

Mainly because of type safety reason, unscoped enum can leak names inside the enums, and the scoped enum doest not have a risk of leak name, the names can only be visbile inside.

There are 2 kinds of enums in c++ so far.

C++98-style unscoped enums:
`enum Color {Red, Green, Yellow};`,
which can implicit convert to int.

C++11 scoped enums: `enum class{Red, Green, Yellow};`,
which cann't be implicit convert to int, can only use a cast to convert to other type, like `static_cast<int>(my_color)`.

Scoped enums have 3 advantage comparing to unscoped enums:

1. Reduce namespace pollution;
2. Strong type safety;
3. Scoped enums may be forward-declared, unscoped enums needs additonal work to be forward-declared;

Meanwhile, Unscoped enums are more flexible than scoped enums.

Both scoped enums and unscoped enums support specification of the underlying type, the default underlying type for scoped enums is `int`. Unscoped enums have no default underlying type, which is compiler dependent, can be a `char` or `int`, according to the range of values.

`enum class Color: std::uint8_t{Red, Green, Yellow}; // Definition`

`enum Color: std::uint8_t{Red, Green, Yellow}; // Forward Declaration`

Unscoped enums may be forward-declared only if ther declaration sepcifies an underlying type.

In Practice, prefer scoped enums to unscoped enums.

See the book "Effective Modern C++" by Scott Meyers, item 10:  prefer scoped enums to unscoped enums.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my mistake, my 4th item is incorrect. I modified it.